# AngularJS: remove/hide a parent but keep the child

Tags: angularjs, parent-child, show-hide

In AngularJS, how do we hide/remove an element without hiding/removing it's children.

```
<div class="hide-or-remove-me">
    <p>Leave me here.</p>
</div>
```

Is there a built in Angular directive?

Comment: How do you do that in normal JavaScript? Surely there is more to the operation, like "How to *replace* the parent with the/a children/child?"

Comment: <div class="hide-or-remove-me" ng-click="show = show!" ng-show="show">
    <p>Leave me here.</p>
</div>
<p ng-click="show = show!" ng-show="!show">leave me here.</p>

Comment: What I am wondering is not how to do it in JavaScript but whether there is a built in Angular directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="hide-or-remove-me" ng-click="show = show!" ng-show="show">
<p>Leave me here.</p>
</div>
<p ng-click="show = show!" ng-show="!show">leave me here.</p>
```

It's my variant.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing. The problem is that I am repeating myself and want not to duplicate the inner content.